# Pyspark - Column transformation causes data shuffle

Tags: python, pyspark, concatenation

I am trying to transform data in Pyspark dataframe in order to export it.
I have arrays like "[1,2,3]", and I need to transform it to a string like "(1;2;3)".
Array need to be concatenated, and parenthesis should be added at beginning and end of the array.
I also need to apply some regex.

Sample input would be like :

| col1 | array1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "First" | [1,2,3] | "a~" |
| "Second" | [4,5,6] | "b" |

Excepted output :

| col1 | array1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "First" | "(1;2;3)" | "a" |
| "Second" | "(4;5;6)" | "b" |

Actual wrong output :

| col1 | array1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "First" | "(4;5;6)" | "a" |
| "Second" | "(X;X;X)" | "b" |

where "(X;X;X)" would be data from another row.

I tried the following code :

```
for c in df.columns:
    if isinstance(df.schema[c].dataType, ArrayType):
        print(c)
        df= df.withColumn(c, concat_ws(';', col(c))).withColumn(c, concat(lit("("), col(c), lit(")"))).withColumn(c, F.regexp_replace(c, '\n|\r|\\n|\\r|~|\\(\\)|', ''))
    else:
        df= df.withColumn(c, F.regexp_replace(c, '\n|\r|\\n|\\r|~|', ''))
```

I make a loop on every column of the Pyspark Dataframe. If the column is an array, I concatenate it and apply the regexp. If not, I only apply the regexp.

The issue is, after those operation, data is shuffled in my columns, and I don't have the data excepted. For example, if column d had "b" as a value for a given row, it would now be "c" or "d" for the same row.

How can I apply those transformations without "shuffling" the data ?
I am not sure that the way I actually loop on each column is a great practice with PySpark, but I really need to apply my function on every column, and check if it's an array or not to adapt the processing.

Comment: could you please add sample input, expected output and current "wrong" output ?

Comment: I added it to the main post and also added some precisions.

Comment: There are no issues with your current code. Please add [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your data, here is the dataframe:

```py
a = [
    ("First", [1, 2, 3], "a~"),
    ("Second", [4, 5, 6], "b"),
]

b = "col1   array1  col2".split()

df = spark.createDataFrame(a,b)

df.show()

+------+---------+----+
|  col1|   array1|col2|
+------+---------+----+
| First|[1, 2, 3]|  a~|
|Second|[4, 5, 6]|   b|
+------+---------+----+
```

I tried you code. Nothing wrong :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

for c in df.columns:
    if isinstance(df.schema[c].dataType, T.ArrayType):
        print(c)
        df = (
            df.withColumn(c, F.concat_ws(";", F.col(c)))
            .withColumn(c, F.concat(F.lit("("), F.col(c), F.lit(")")))
            .withColumn(c, F.regexp_replace(c, "\n|\r|\\n|\\r|~|\\(\\)|", ""))
        )
    else:
        df = df.withColumn(c, F.regexp_replace(c, "\n|\r|\\n|\\r|~|", ""))

df.show()

+------+-------+----+
|  col1| array1|col2|
+------+-------+----+
| First|(1;2;3)|   a|
|Second|(4;5;6)|   b|
+------+-------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Seems like we got some strange interaction on our cluster, with memory usage. Sometimes it does the shuffle, but I get the right result if I start from a clean notebook.